# How to mount a SD Card which was formatted with exfat by a Lumix G9 camera?

Tags: linux, mount, sd-card, camera, exfat

The SD card was formatted by a Panasonic Lumix G9.

```
mount /dev/sde1  /mnt/sd/ -t exfat

ls -1 /mnt/sd/DCIM/
100_PANA
101_PANA
```

The pictures in `100_PANA` are displayed in the camera, but the mounted folder is empty.
I can only see the pictures and movies in `101_PANA`, when it is mounted on Linux.

```
System information 
Kernel: 5.10.52
exfat: sys-fs/exfat-utils-1.3.0
Cameras tested: Lumix G9, Lumix DMC-TZ101
SD Cards: 2x SanDisk ExtremePro 128 GB, 1x SanDisk ExtremePro 64 GB
OS: Most tests on Gentoo Linux, also tested on Linux Mint 20.1
Cardreader: Kingston FCR-HS4, and the built in reader of an Lenovo T430
```

How should I mount the card properly?

Comment: Stupid question, that camera apparently has 2 card slots, the images aren't on the other one, are they? Other than that,. I've no idea

Answer (score 1):

After removing `sys-fs/exfat-utils-1.3.0` and using the internal kernel `exfat` support, I can see all files again.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues on manjaro. None of my G9 formatted SD cards could be accessed. I could mount them fine, it even displayed the correct folder structure, but I after I tried to do anything with the picture it would just show an empty folder in the file-browser.

If I tried to access the SD card from the terminal it would give me the following error: `cannot access 'LUMIX': Transport endpoint is not connected`

After your suggestion I've removed my `exfat-utils` package with pacman
and it's now working flawlessly.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/420236)